# What mode should I use to install R packages? Source or Binary?

Tags: r, installation, binary

In the past, my R defaulted to installing from source, so I learnt (by habit) to say NO to "source" prompt. Lately, R doesn't prompt me. It just defaults to binary.

1. Can some knowledge soul confirm for me if R automatically switches to compile from
   source if it doesn't find the binary version?
2. I saw some suggest to disable "Source" installing somewhere (may be .Rprofile file).
   Is this hack okay?
3. In the .Rprofile file, you can list download mirrors with your preferred mode:

   ```
   options(repos = c(
     binary = "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest", // for windows
     source = "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest",
     CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org",
   ))
   ```

   Is this the only option to have it switch?
4. Sometimes the package is archived so I have to download it as tar.gz.
   Does R need to compile this compressed file from source?
   Can't tar.gz be installed as binary? I have the impression that Centos RPM does that ...

Comment: The choice between binary and source packages is not made in the `options("repos")` setting, it's made on `install.packages(.., type="source")` or such. The fact that you have `binary=` and `source=` in your `repos=` options is unrecognized by R, it will look at both URLs as if they were different and choose one ... the fact that they are identical may be lost to the underlying functions (I haven't dived deeply into the code ... maybe they `unique(.)` the URLs, but I have no reason to believe that at this point).

Comment: To your Q1, if you read [`?install.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html), it defaults to `"source"` except on windows and some macos builds. Traditionally, the remaining users either had to use an OS-level mechanism for binary installs (DirkEddelbeuttel mains debian packages) or compile from source, always. Lately, Posit's packagemanager provides binary R packages for many linux distributions, so that is a great option. If R is supposed to look for a binary version, it will do so, and then fall back on source if it is found instead.

Comment: Q2: if you specify `type="binary"`, I _think_ (without verifying atm) that it will fail if not found. Have you tried it? Q3: see my first comment, that is not the way to specify binary vs source installs. What those options do is say that if the package is not found on Posit's PM, then look on CRAN. Q4: It depends. On CRAN, typically `.tar.gz` files are source and `.zip` files are binary packages, but I don't think that's the case on Posit's PM. You can look at the archive, and if it contains (e.g.) `./help/aliases.db` then it is a binary package otherwise likely a source package.

Comment: This isn’t RStudio. It’s R.